# How can menu item key equivalents using characters requiring shifting be easily set without the shift modifier in IB?

Tags: macos, interface-builder, keyboard-shortcuts

#### The set-up:

In Interface Builder 3.2.5, when you set a key equivalent for a menu item using a character that is typed using a shift key (e.g. the question mark), the key equivalent is set to the unshifted character on the same key with the shift modifier as part of the key equiv. For example, trying to set the key equiv. to Command-Question Mark sets it as Command-Shift-Forward Slash.

The various system U.S. and Dvorak layouts, the Unicode Hex Input, British and Canadian English layouts and my custom Dvorak layout all exhibit this behavior.

#### The question:

How can an equiv be easily set to a character requiring use of a shift key without including the shift modifier as part of the equiv?

#### The workarounds:

It could be done by switching to a keyboard layout where you can type the desired character without using shift. It could also be done by editing the nib file containing the menu. However, neither of these has the level of ease I desire. It could be done programmatically, but (for the purposes of this question) I'm only interested in how it could be done in IB.

---

So far, the Apple docs and web searches have turned up naught. If any resource online answers this question, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IB 3 you the button should allow you to click the arrows to pop up a menu after you type something that is an alternate.
[image: IB3 Picture]

In [Xcode 4](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id422352214?mt=12) it is more apparent as you type in ⇧⌘/ it has a drop down `Alternates` that lets you pick ⌘?

[image: Xcode Picture]

Comment: You know, the "Key Equiv." field in the IB 3.2.5 inspector is a dropdown. I thought I had tried it and it didn't do anything, but I tried it again after typing "⌘-⇧-/", and it gave me the option of "⌘-?" as a key equiv. Works when setting the key equiv from both the inspector and menu preview.

Comment: @outis I think we all feel dumb, even more strangely I had to go to an old computer that still had IB3 on it to do a corrected screen shot, its' running IB 3.1.2. Without clicking on the menu, it would do ⌘-? everytime.

Comment: At least my question is answered, no matter how much our foreheads hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, example on a german keyboard(the ? is on the same key as ß), I managed to get CMD+?, here we go:

1. click the Key Equiv field so it's highlighted
2. hold shift
3. press ? once
4. press cmd once
5. release hold on shift

Alright, it does seem impossible for US Keyboards to get CMD+? working in IB3. I've managed to to set CMD+? in IB4 though with a US Keyboard. Look at the screenshot.

**Interface Builder 3**

[image]

**Interface Builder 4**

[image]

**German Keyboard Layout**
It's two key to the left of the backspace key.

[image]

Comment: Didn't work for ⌘-? (it still set the key equiv to ⇧-⌘-/ ), and I was so hopeful. Tried it in both the inspector window and menu preview.

Comment: Have a look at the new combo.

Comment: Same result with the U.S., Dvorak and my custom Dvorak layout: ⇧-⌘-/, thought it works if I switch to the German layout. Maybe an examination of the key layout file would reveal why, but I think the system layouts are no longer accessible. Just realized I didn't mention which version of IB, but it looks to be the same as you have.

Comment: IB4 seems to work with US Keyboard. I am not sure why it doesn't work with the german layout for you. I'll post a pic so you can find the correct key.

Comment: Actually, the second approach (the one currently displayed, ⇧-/,⇧-⌘) worked with the German layout when I tested it. I just don't like the idea of having a layout I won't use for anything else active, and having to switch to it just to set a key equiv.